# Twilio Studio - Connect Call To Timeout

Tags: twilio

Using Twilio Studio and our flow is set to "Connect Call To" widget a generic phone unless an extension is entered, then "Connect Call To" widget a person's desk phone, this is using the "Split Based Upon" widget.  Problem occurs when a user does not pick up their phone and a timeout occurs.  How does the flow send the user back to the Twilio "Record Voicemail" widget?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you found the answer useful, please upvote it and accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a *Split Based Upon* after *Call Complete*. In the *Variable To Test* dropdown box, type `{{widgets.connect_call_1.DialCallStatus}}` (replace `connect_call_1` with the name of your widget).

Create a transition for *Equal To* `no-answer`. Connect this to a *Say/Play* and then to a *Record Voicemail*. Leave *No Match* disconnected so that the call will end if the targeted extension hangs up. [image: Studio Flow showing setup described]

Comment: This is weird, Call Completed seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure this out. The previous answers don't have the up to date Twilio "Connect Call To" feature documented.

1. Create a "Connect Call To" widget.
2. On the "Connected Call Ended" option, connect that to a "Split Based On" widget.
3. Check [Call Status Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) for more information but we'll want to do is check if the `DialCallStatus` of the Connect Call To widget value is equal to `no-answer`, `failed`, and `busy`. That way if the caller you are trying to connect to either pushes end before call connects, it times out, or it fails for whatever reason, it'll send you to the next thing.

I've attached a picture below for reference.

[image]

Comment: What do I do if I get the "hangup" event returned? I've put my timeout to 60 seconds, but my phone will go to voicemail at about 20 seconds, and then i receive the 'hangup' event. It doesnt match with any of the mentioned statuses in the documentation. 
My logs show me: Widget Class: Make Outgoing Call , Event: hangup , Transitioned to: Ended

Answer (score -1):

From my testing, this would work in one instance, the caller NOT hanging up. If the caller does hang up the call will remain in an active engagement status as the dialCallStatus matches "no-answer" for both a hung-up call AND a call which the target user did not pick up the line.